# How to implement displaying one tip per day in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show one tip per day in an iOS app. I have already done this for Android, but I am not getting how to do it in iOS.

I have a file where I have written tip and picking tip from the file randomly, now I want to display one tip per day.

I have tried `UILocalNotification`, but it did not help.

```
UILocalNotification *locNot = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSInterval interval = 24 * 60 * 60;

locNot.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: interval fromDate: now];
locNot.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: locNot];
[locNot release];
```

So is it a correct way of doing it? In Xcode, it is giving me:

> error undeclared identifier interval...

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` instead of `NSInterval` ?. Adding a day to `NSDate` should be done with `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: So you want to display the tip as a notification or you want to display the tip the next time the user opens the app?  I know as a user I would do everything possible to stop an annoying notification tip.

Comment: Just a sidenote why are you releasing locNot? You should be using ARC. Some info about ARC here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting

Comment: @Droppy...I want to display the tip when user tap on Tip of the Day button not notification...i did not find any way on the google so tried the above code found somewhere...i am newbie to iOS....very less knowledge in iOS....

Comment: I imagine what you need is a UIView. If you want it to "pop up" or animate maybe this will be helpful https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip

Comment: I want to display one tip per day...i mean next day tip should be different.as the device date changes tip should be changed....

Answer (score 0):

u missed this `NSTimeInterval *time = (int)24 * 60 * 60;`

Comment: Should be `NSTimeInterval time = 24 * 60 * 60;` otherwise you will end up having a pointer to a `NSTimerInterval`, plus no need to convert to int since `NSTimeInterval` is declared as a double.

Comment: I want to display one tip per day...i mean next day tip should be different.as the device date changes tip should be changed....